# scanf() not giving correct values for entered doubles

Tags: c, input, double, scanf, lf

```
double low = 0 , high = 0.0,n = 0.0;
----
printf("Enter the integral limits (low high): ");
scanf("%lf %lf", &low, &high);

printf("%lf%lf",low,high);
printf("Enter the number of subinternals (n): ");
scanf("%lf",&n);
```

When I test this program (by

```
    printf("%lf%lf",low,high);) (6th line)
```

I get values of 0.000000 and 0.000000 for low and high. I initialized them at the beginning of the program and now I'm trying to input values for them.

What am I doing wrong?

{P.S. I'm on a windows 7 laptop. and I've already tried changing the "%f" to "%lf" and back to "%f")

What should I do? 
(HELP PLEASE!)

EDIT:
I'm not sure what just happened.
I error checked with

```
        if (2 != scanf("%lf %lf", &low, &high))
               printf("scanf failed!\n")
```

and what happened instead was that after my "..(low high): "
I entered 1 and 2, and then the program was waiting for more input, and then I entered 1 and 2 again, and this time, it gave the right prinft... not sure what happened?

Output screen:
http://s1288.photobucket.com/user/Kdragonflys/media/ss_zps6b85396e.png.html

Comment: Strongly recommend to check the `scanf()` results: `if (2 != scanf("%lf%lf", &low, &high)) handle_error();`

Comment: And `\n` at the end of the `printf`s. (Or `fflush(stdout);`).

Comment: Note: The `l` in `printf("%lf%lf",low,high)` is optional.  Same result with/without an `l`.  Not so with `scanf()`.

Comment: What's the difference between lf and f?

Comment: I get "implicit declaration of function 'handle_error'..." (program doesn't run)

Answer (score 2):

You need `%lf` for `double`s with `scanf`, and you also need two of these if you have two `double`s to read.

So change:

```
scanf("%f", &low, &high);
```

to:

```
scanf("%lf %lf", &low, &high);
```

Also change:

```
scanf("%f",&n);
```

to:

```
scanf("%lf",&n);
```

---

Note: error checking is always a good idea - `scanf` returns the number of values successfully processed. So you could check whether the first `scanf` call is working like this:

```
if (scanf("%lf %lf", &low, &high) != 2)
    printf("scanf failed!\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
double low = 0.0 , high = 0.0,n = 0.0;
----
printf("Enter the integral limits (low high): ");
scanf("%lf %lf", &low, &high);

printf("%lf %lf",low,high);
printf("Enter the number of subinternals (n): ");
scanf("%lf",&n);
```

Comment: Still isn't outputting low and high as the values I inputed.

Comment: Can you show me which values you are entering for low and high?

Comment: I entered 1 and 2. ( see edit above) something new happened when I error checked.

Comment: My output screen: http://s1288.photobucket.com/user/Kdragonflys/media/ss_zps6b85396e.png.html